# Detached screen on a remote host

Tags: shell, ssh, gnu-screen

I have a local script that runs a remote script via ssh. The local script is  minecraft.php:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i {$this->pemkey} {$this->ssh_user} sudo /vol/start_bukkit.sh
```

The remote script is /vol/start_bukkit.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/vol/bukkit"
/usr/bin/screen -S bukkit -m -d /usr/local/bin/java -Xnoclassgc -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /vol/bukkit/craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

What happens is that the java command works, launching craftbukkit.jar, but screen doesn't launch a new window. What's going on? How can a new window be created?

If I sign in to the remote server and run start_bukkit.sh then screen works as expected, creating a newly detached window running craftbukkit.jar in it.

**EDIT:**

I got it to work. I updated the local script by removing the sudo and putting the screen command in. Here it is:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i {$this->pemkey} {$this->ssh_user} /usr/bin/screen -S bukkit -m -d /vol/start_bukkit.sh
```

On the remote side I removed the screen command:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/vol/bukkit"
/usr/local/bin/java -Xnoclassgc -Xms1024M -Xmx1024M -jar /vol/bukkit/craftbukkit.jar nogui
```

I can't explain why this works.

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing a psuedo-tty with your `ssh` command.

```
ssh -t -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i
{$this->pemkey} {$this->ssh_user} sudo /vol/start_bukkit.sh


man 1 ssh

     -t      Force pseudo-tty allocation.  This can be used to execute
             arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which 
             can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  
             Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has 
             no local tty.
```

Also, in your script `start_bukkit.sh`, you don't have a PATH set. You call `java` without an absolute path, so it may not be found. Either set a PATH at the beginning of the script (best practice), or call `java` via the absolute path (`/usr/bin/java`).

Comment: If I add ssh -t option then the screen window is not created AND the java program is not started.

Comment: BTW, I updated java to the absolute path.